# Upload files to same random folder in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am uploading two files using django rest framework, i want to upload these two files into the same folder and create said folder with a random name.

So far I can upload both files to different random folders using the following:

```
from uuid import uuid4

def path_and_rename(path, dataset):
    def wrapper(instance, filename):
        main_folder = '{}/{}/'.format(path, uuid4().hex)
        name = '{}.csv'.format(dataset)

        return os.path.join(main_folder, name)
    return wrapper


class Dataset(Model):
    trainFile = FileField(null=False, blank=False,
                      validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['csv'])],
                      upload_to=path_and_rename('files/', 'train'))
    testFile = FileField(null=False, blank=False,
                     validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['csv'])],
                     upload_to=path_and_rename('files/', 'test'))


class DatasetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Dataset
        fields = (
            'id',
            'trainFile',
            'testFile',
        )
        read_only_fields = ('created',)
```

How could I get both files to be uploaded to the same random folder?

Comment: Not make it random...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `path_to_rename()`, and in turn `uuid4()` on two separate occasions so you're going to get two random UUIDs. As a sidenote, for better code readability, your "wrapper" should be the outer function.

Try:

```
def upload_to_wrapper(upload_dir, dataset):
    def path_and_rename(instance, filename):
        return os.path.join(upload_dir, '{}.csv'.format(dataset))
    return path_and_rename


class Dataset(Model):
    upload_dir = 'files/{}'.format(uuid4().hex)
    trainFile = FileField(null=False, blank=False,
                          validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['csv'])],
                          upload_to=upload_to_wrapper(upload_dir, 'train'))
    testFile = FileField(null=False, blank=False,
                         validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['csv'])],
                         upload_to=upload_to_wrapper(upload_dir, 'test'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the first `FileField` is required and the fields will be uploaded in order, you could use an alternate `upload_to` function for all of your fields apart from the first that relies on the initial upload path. Something like:

```
import posixpath

def dataset_file(dataset):
    def wrapper(instance, filename):
        main_folder = posixpath.split(instance.trainFile)[0]
        name = '{}.csv'.format(dataset)
        return posixpath.join(main_folder, name)
    return wrapper
```

```